# Convert a document to PDF format

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf

I've an XML Document that needs to be Converted to PDF, I've good knowledge of XSLt, but here when i'm trying to enter output format to PDF it is not taking it. When i searched online, i knew that the output formats of XSLT can be text/xml/html. But i need a pdf output.

And also I've the below questions,

```
1) If i attach a stylesheet to XSLT, will the styles be saved in PDF output.
2) Can this PDF be importable into InDesign and editable(if any changes are required).
```

Thanks

Comment: take a look at XSL-FO

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you please gimme some example if you don't mind, as i'm unable to relater XSLT with XSL:FO

Comment: try this site (http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/resources.html)

Answer (score 2):

The general approach is that you use XSLT to convert your XML document to XSL-FO. XSL-FO is an XML vocabulary that essentially describes the layout of pages; it defines elements for pages and regions of a page. Once you have generated the XSL-FO, you put it through an XSL-FO processor which turns it into PDF with no further user involvement.

Don't expect to learn XSL-FO by looking at one or two examples. You'll need to do some reading.

Answer (score 1):

PDF is not one of the standard output formats of XSLT. The `method` attribute of `xsl:output` allows the following values:

```
xml | html | xhtml | text | [lexical QName]
```

The last value means that any qualified name can be used - as long as a product or user *extension* is provided to resolve its meaning. But writing your own extension to an XSLT processor is not exactly what you had in mind, I'd daresay.

But PDF generation is not the purpose of XSLT anyway, because it is primarily concerned with *transforming* XML, whereas formatting is left to a related specification, *Formatting Objects*, or XSL-FO. Find the official recommendation [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/).

XSL-FO is written in XML as well, but the elements are typically prefixed with the XSL-FO namespace:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
```

Note that XSL-FO code cannot be interpreted by an XSLT processor (that is, you can transform XSL-FO documents but you cannot render it as PDF). For this task, an FO processor must be used. For example, [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) is a well-known and free one.

---

Now, how to proceed? Split your enterprise of generating PDF in two parts: Transform your XML input to XSL-FO in a first step (using an XSLT stylesheet) and in a second step render the result with an FO processor.